# Excel add-in auto close download file pop-up

Tags: excel, office-js, office-js-helpers

We are using Excel Add-in side loaded for our application. We have developed download file feature which downloads base64 content as a file. Each time a file is downloaded, a downloads pop-up is showing up from excel add-in. Is there an option to auto close the downloads pop-up so we don't have to click on close button each time.

[image: Downloads pop-up screenshot]

Tried to change browser settings for add-in which is supposed to be Internet explorer. Since IE is now redirected to edge browser, I have turned off Show downloads menu when a download starts option in download settings at edge://settings/downloads. But this doesn't seem to help in excel add-in.